# Power apps cant get table function to work with semicolon

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I simply cant get the table function to work with semicolon (which I also don't know how to change to comma).

My code is really simple:

```
Table(
{Value: "Item 1"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen};
{Value: "Item 2"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen};
{Value: "Item 3"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen};
{Value: "Item 4"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen};
{Value: "Item 5"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen};
{Value: "Item 6"; Icon: Icon.Waypoint; Screen: App.ActiveScreen})
```

I need this table as part of my left sided menubar and none of the columns are defined.. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Best,

Nick

Comment: I believe this issue of comma and semicolon arises when your browser language is other than english. If your browser language is english then go by comma rather than semicolon. [Table function for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table)

Comment: Are you getting this table's values from somewhere that doesn't allow you to change them? Just wondering what the blocker is for unable to change the semicolons to commas. String manipulation would be pretty tricky in this situation, might have to use some Regex expression.